# Is this (self intersecting) surface considered one sided?

Tags: surfaces, orientation, stokes-theorem

I wanted to apply stokes theorem on a curve (in black) that possibly looks like the seam of a tennis ball. I make a surface by drawing a line from the origin to each point of this curve.

I get a surface like this and wanted to know if it's actually one sided or not - since I wasn't sure how you can cross the intersection bits, whether you carry on as you would expect - or you move from one part to the other on the intersection instead of crossing the edge (black curve).

[image: view 1]

[image: view 2]

[image: view 3]

[image: view 4]

The reason why I am using a surface like this is because I can explicitly define the normal along it for my problem.

(mathematica code):

```
tennisballseam[n_, a_, b_, c_][t_] := {-a*(Cos[t]*(b^2 + c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2) + 
  c^2*n^3*Sin[t]*Sin[2*n*t]/2)/(Sqrt[
   b^2*Cos[t]^2 + c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2 + a^2*Sin[t]^2]*
  Sqrt[a^2*b^2*Cos[t]^4 + b^2*c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2*Sin[t]^2 + 
    a^2*b^2*Sin[t]^4 + a^2*c^2*n^4*Sin[t]^2*Sin[n*t]^2 + 
    Cos[t]^2*(a^2*c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2 + 
       b^2*(2*a^2*Sin[t]^2 + c^2*n^4*Sin[n*t]^2)) + 
    a^2*c^2*n^3*Sin[2*t]*Sin[2*n*t]/2 - 
    b^2*c^2*n^3*Sin[2*t]*Sin[2*n*t]/2]),b*(-2*(a^2 + c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2)*Sin[t] + 
  c^2*n^3*Cos[t]*Sin[2*n*t])/(2*
  Sqrt[b^2*Cos[t]^2 + c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2 + a^2*Sin[t]^2]*
  Sqrt[a^2*b^2*Cos[t]^4 + b^2*c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2*Sin[t]^2 + 
    a^2*b^2*Sin[t]^4 + a^2*c^2*n^4*Sin[t]^2*Sin[n*t]^2 + 
    Cos[t]^2*(a^2*c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2 + 
       b^2*(2*a^2*Sin[t]^2 + c^2*n^4*Sin[n*t]^2)) + 
    a^2*c^2*n^3*Sin[2*t]*Sin[2*n*t]/2 - 
    b^2*c^2*n^3*Sin[2*t]*Sin[2*n*t]/2]), -c*n*((a^2 - b^2)*Cos[t]*Cos[n*t]*Sin[t] + b^2*n*Cos[t]^2*Sin[n*t] + 
  a^2*n*Sin[t]^2*Sin[n*t])/(Sqrt[
   b^2*Cos[t]^2 + c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2 + a^2*Sin[t]^2]*
  Sqrt[a^2*b^2*Cos[t]^4 + b^2*c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2*Sin[t]^2 + 
    a^2*b^2*Sin[t]^4 + a^2*c^2*n^4*Sin[t]^2*Sin[n*t]^2 + 
    Cos[t]^2*(a^2*c^2*n^2*Cos[n*t]^2 + 
       b^2*(2*a^2*Sin[t]^2 + c^2*n^4*Sin[n*t]^2)) + 
    a^2*c^2*n^3*Sin[2*t]*Sin[2*n*t]/2 - 
    b^2*c^2*n^3*Sin[2*t]*Sin[2*n*t]/2])};

ParametricPlot3D[{(tennisballseam[2, 2.8, 2.8, 1][t] + 
 2) z, (tennisballseam[2, 2.8, 2.8, 1][t] + 2)}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0,6 \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 20, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red, Thick}]
```

Comment: I think this still counts as a two-sided surface, because you can define a consistently oriented normal field. In fact because you are connecting a closed curve to a point, this is just an immersion of a disk into 3-space (with the center of the disk mapped to the origin and the circumference mapped to the curve).

Comment: @Rahul: What do you mean by "consistently oriented" normal field, and where do you see one in the question?

Comment: @Alex If we treat the given surface as parameterized by $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R^3:(s,t)\mapsto sc(t)$ "glued" along $f(s,0)=f(s,1)$, where $c:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^3$ is the input closed curve, then we can define the normal at any point $(s,t)$ on the parameterization by normalizing the vector $c(t)\times c'(t)$. This normal vector field is "consistent" in that the normals point in the same direction on both sides of the gluing (unlike the Möbius strip, where the normals necessarily point in opposite directions).

Comment: @Alex Sorry if my terminology is sloppy; I'm not a topologist nor a differential geometer.

Comment: @Rahul: ...provided that $c(t) \times c'(t) \ne 0 \ \forall t$, which is not obvious from just a picture; we need the explicit equation of $c$ (remember that a surface is orientable if there exist a smooth *non-zero* normal field).

Comment: @Alex That's true. Personally I was willing to believe (from the shape of the isoparametric contours) that $c(t)$ and $c'(t)$ were never parallel, and I was addressing the issue of self-intersections instead.

Comment: @Rahul: In fact, we do have the explicit equation, but... it's not really usable.

Comment: ah, okay thanks a lot for the help both of you :)